# Problem crawling a link that contains: '#'

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to use scrapy to crawl pages of a 'category' in a website.
so I go on my way and get the number of pages.
and when i try to use response.follow(link, callback)
it only works one time and the response.link inside the callback does not contain the page number
my code:

```
for category_page in self.category_pages:
    link = category_page['catLink']
    if(link[-1]=="/"):
        link= link[:-1]
    else:
        pass
    total_pages = category_page['numPages']
    i = 1
    while i <= total_pages:
        next_url = link + f"/#{str(i)}/"
        print(next_url)
        yield response.follow(next_url, callback=self.parse_catPage)
        i += 1
```

tried ignoring the robots.txt but no success,
it "works" when i remove the # from the link tho

Comment: The fragment identifier (the part after the `#`) is not even sent to the server, and has no possible effect on what your request retrieves.  It is used to auto-scroll to an anchor of the same name on the page, and is available to Javascript on the page to do whatever it wants (perhaps the loaded page is just a skeleton, and the Javascript uses the fragment identifier to dynamically load the specified page number).

Answer (score 1):

"#" is probably just an anchor like my predecessor already said. Use networking tools to find loadresult and fetch request forms to ur script. My bet is its ajax calls but cant say more without targeted url.